# What values does SAS's PROC GENMOD return when convergence is not achieved?

Tags: regression, sas

More specifically, are they statistics at the end of the last iteration? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "returned". If you're looking at the displayed output, you'll see a warning if the convergence criterion is not met, and standard errors may not be displayed with coefficient estimates.

If you're not looking at displayed output (using the `noprint` option, for example), you can look at the [ODS table](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_sect058.htm) called `ConvergenceStatus`. To use this, just add

```
ods output ConvergenceStatus=_dataset_name_you_want;
```

before your `proc` statement.

Comment: By "returned" I mean the statistics that are shown in the output. This has all the statistics, i.e. the deviance, log-likelihood, estimated coefficients, the standard errors, the Wald 95% confidence limits, ChiSq and Pr > ChiSq. In case of non-convergence, I want to make sense of these reported values.

Comment: Oh, you're asking what the coefficients mean if convergence isn't achieved. Not much. These are estimates from a point on the likelihood function that hasn't been maximized.

Comment: Thanks. Even I thought so. But I can't find anything in the document which say so.

Answer (score 0):

The output from proc genmod is just from whatever stage the fitting algorithm reached when it stopped. Sometimes the output is useful; the algorithm was making (slow) progress, but hit the iteration limit before it could converge. In this case, you can often use what's printed as a rough approximation to the correct solution.

Other times, the algorithm may have blown up: it's trying to taking the log of a negative number, or encounted numeric overflow, or the iterations are diverging. In this case, you may not be able to get anything usable.

In general, you can get a clue on which of these happened by checking for implausibly large numbers (or missing values) in the output. Estimates of that are a couple of orders of magnitude larger than you expect would point to likely overflow, for example.